# Sending information through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new in React and i got stuck, i basically want to make the text in the input show in a div when the button "send" is clicked, but the way i thought it could work, it's not. In the console the message is shown, but not in the div. Could someone help me, please?

That's the code:

```
const [chatText, getChatText] = useState('');

const getInputValue = (e) => {
    getChatText(e.target.value)
}

const getMessage = () => {
    console.log(chatText)
    return (
        <MessageReceiver 
            message={chatText}
        />
    )

}

return (
    <>
        <input 
            onChange={getInputValue}
            value={chatText}
            placeholder="Type a message"
        />
        <button onClick={() => getMessage()}>Send</button>
    </>
)
```

The MessageReceiver is only a div with a props to receive the text.

Comment: I can't see a single div in your codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a component from the function for the button `onClick` event.
To solve your problem you can add a new flag to the state to check if a message were send.
Try something like this:

```
const [chatText, getChatText] = useState("");
const [isMessageReceived, setIsMessageReceived] = useState(false);

const getInputValue = (e) => {
  getChatText(e.target.value);
};

const getMessage = () => {
  setIsMessageReceived = true;
};

return (
  <>
    <input
      onChange={getInputValue}
      value={chatText}
      placeholder="Type a message"
    />
    <button onClick={() => getMessage()}>Send</button>
    {isMessageReceived && <MessageReceiver message={chatText} />}
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually rendering the MessageReceiver on the webpage just returning it either set a variable to this and render it on dom using state or just create a state variable to hide then show this MessageReceiver component.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution

Render the message card in the return of the function.

```
const [chatText, getChatText] = useState('');
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const getInputValue = (e) => {
    getChatText(e.target.value)
}


return (
    <>
        <input 
            onChange={getInputValue}
            value={chatText}
            placeholder="Type a message"
        />
        <button onClick={() =>setShoow(true)}>Send</button>
       { show 
           ? <MessageReceiver  message={chatText} /> 
       : null}
    </>
)
```

> Explanation:

You're not rendering the MessageCard as it is not returning by your main component. Just maintain a flag for showing the MessageCard and set it on click of send button.